# How do I migrate a mysql database from mediawiki 1.14.0 to mediawiki 1.32.0?

Tags: mediawiki, database-migration

Godaddy is forcing old servers offline and I have no choice but to migrate my old mediawiki service to a new server.
I had to maintain the old versions due to use of extensions which I fear are either gone or different now.

Here are the relevant versions:

- Source: mediawiki 1.14.0, PHP 5.1.6 (apache2handler), MySQL 5.0.77
- Target: mediawiki 1.32.0, PHP 7.2.15, MySQL 5.7.25, ICU 60.2

I have copies of all contents of /var/lib/mysql/ from the old server copied to the new one in a backup directory, and I have mysql dumps copied over too.

Is it possible to simply put the database tree from Source into Target under a different name and then modify LocalSettings.php?

If not, can the mysql dump be restored to do the job?

Extensions have changed and I will have to review hundreds of pages to check for problems.

Any advice on how to do this with the least problems is welcome.

Also, I might consider hiring a contractor to review the task and supervise my work.  It would have to be someone who has done migrations of this sort before, or someone with other clear sufficient experience.

Comment: I read mediawiki markdown with ease.  If there is a way to dump the page SOURCES by using wget recursively to fetch the contents of the edit field in edit pages, that would be far better than fidgeting with mysql.  So, is there a recursive wget or curl command which will download the page sources?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is, painfully. That's about a decade's worth of changes. There isn't any magic spell that will make applying them less hard than it sounds; you'll have to import the old database, run `update.php`, and prepare for debugging any errors that might occur as you will be using an upgrade path that few if any people have taken before you.

Alternatively, you might export the content (`maintenance/dumpBackup.php` existed in 1.14) and reimport into the new wiki, and accept losing and having to recreate everything that's not content or content history (like user records).

> Is it possible to simply put the database tree from Source into Target under a different name and then modify LocalSettings.php?

Yes, although I'm not sure what you win by using a different name.

Comment: I appreciate your input.  dumpBackup has a flaw and throws an error without doing anything.  I tried to fix it, but failed.  I have been transferring by hand, but it has already been several hundred pages and I have a long way to go.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You could use [pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) or a similar tool. Also, you can report errors at the MediaWiki [support forum](https://discourse-mediawiki.wmflabs.org) or [bug tracker](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. I can only strongly recommend to read the release notes for any version carefully, especially for database changes and changes on how skins and extensions are loaded in the LocalSettings.php. For example the way the skins work change around version 1.24 IIRIC.

Also, be sure to create a renamed copy of your 1.14 LocalSettings.php and create a fresh one during the upgrade via the installer, the old one will cause a multitude of exceptions. You may also need to run the database upgrade several times.
Also make sure you move your old 1.14 wiki installation to an extra folder and upload a fresh mediawiki installation, do not just overwrite your existing files in the 1.14 one with the new mediawiki version.

In the end, I went the long route and upgraded version by version first on a local XAMPP dump, then on the server after I identified all the issues for each version upgrade, checked the release notes for each version and made the required changes to my custom skins, replaced deprecated extensions etc.

Good luck.

Comment: Good idea.  I don't think I have the time to go the long way.  I have about a dozen mediawikis on the machine, all at 1.14, and several extensions, some of which have disappeared in the latest offerings (i.e. gnuplot).  I will just have to lose some material by doing it the longest way; visit every old page, go into edit mode, copy, visit new page, go into edit mode, paste, and then try to fix anything that looks wrong.  Thanks for the ideas.